# How does NFS client know changes made on server by other client?

Tags: linux, nfs, nas, san

Is there any way NFS client machine to know about changes made on remote file system by another client? How can it know - "Which new files are created, deleted or modified"? NFS share is mounted on Linux machine.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: It gets the changes from the server. It might not notice them immediately due to caching.